# How to save a figure produced by tikz save/export as JPG/PNG file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, png, jpeg

I have created various plots using the `pgfplots` package for my thesis. Now I would export them in jpg or png format. Does it exist a way to achieve this purpose?

Comment: Both formats are bitmaps, and so do not scale. Keeping as PDFs would be much better.

Comment: Look at section 7.1 in the documentation of `pgfplots`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have installed [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) as the following code uses ImageMagick's `convert` command.

Once you have had a PDF output, you need to convert it to PNG by using the following batch file named `pdf2png.bat`. It is convenient to register the batch path to the system variable.

```
rem pdf2png.bat
echo off
rem %1 PDF filename without extension
rem %2 density
rem %3 alpha, choose one of {on,off,remove}

del "%~1-*.png"

convert -compose copy -bordercolor red -border 3x3 -density %2 -alpha %3 "%~1.pdf" "%~1-%%02d.png"
```

Notes:

- `%1` is the first mandatory argument that specifies the filename (without extension) of your PDF to convert.
- `%2` is the second mandatory argument that specifies the density. The higher density makes the PNG dimension larger.
- `%3` is the third mandatory argument that specifies whether or not you preserve the transparency. Use `on` if you want to preserve the transparency, otherwise choose `remove`. I don't use `off` because it produces a lousy output.
- I added an additional feature such that the output will be enclosed by a red rectangle. If you don't like this feature, remove `-compose copy -bordercolor red -border 3x3` from the code above.

### Exercise

It is just an example. Your scenario in which you get a PDF might be different from mine. My scenario is as follows: compile the following input file with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` to get a PDF output.

```
% myfilename.tex

\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}{gridlabels=0}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](4,3)
    \pstGeonode[
        PointName=none,
        PointSymbol={x,none,x},
        dotscale=2]
    (0,0){A}
    (1,3){B}
    (4,1){C}
    \psline(A)(B)(C)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

You can invoke the batch from the editor of your choice, but here I invoke the batch from the DOS prompt:

[image]

The output is:

[image]

The red rectangle is the border produced by `-compose copy -bordercolor red -border 3x3`.

## Attention!

For Windows users, the `convert` alone no longer works. Instead it must be preceded by both `magick` and a space because `convert` has a special meaning in Windows.

Comment: But in this way I convert all the document or only the image?

Comment: @Mazzy: Only the image if you put each plot into a separate, compilable TeX input file. Use `standalone` document class for each plot.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91188/shell-script-which-parses-tex-files-for-figures/91203#91203 for one way to extract all the `figure` environments. The script there could be modified to produce one file per figure.

Comment: Here's a more standard, non-batch version (works for IM 7.0.10-62): `convert -density 200 -alpha on example.pdf example.png` for 200 DPI and preserving transparency. If using a greyscale, you may want to include `-strip` ([more info](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/884)).

Answer (score 9):

You can automate the process by modifying the externalisation command as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22161 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40795

Here is what I personally would use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]

\tikzset{
    png export/.style={
        % First we call ImageMagick; change settings to requirements
        external/system call/.add={}{; magick convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"},
        % Now we force the PNG figure to be used instead of the PDF
        /pgf/images/external info,
        /pgf/images/include external/.code={
            \includegraphics[width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]{##1.png}
        },
    }
}

\begin{document}

{
% Here we specify the figure will be converted and inserted as PNG
\tikzset{png export}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}

% This figure will be inserted as PDF
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Because It allows me to convert only the figures that I want to convert. See the first link if you need the conversion to be done for all figures.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Texmaker, it offers an option in the document preview window when *right-clicking* to "Convert page to png image".

[image]

TeXstudio doesn't have this option AFAIK. You can still use ImageMagick's PDF to PNG convert (or any other image editor like GIMP):

```
convert figure.pdf figure.png
```

Sample code:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Vertex[x=-2,y=0]{1}
    \Vertex[x=1,y=2]{2}
    \Vertex[x=1,y=-2]{3}
    \Edge(1)(2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Acrobat Reader allows for saving a PDF as JPG. Just compile each LaTeX file. Open them in Acrobat and Save As JPG.

Comment: The newest Acrobat Reader (version 2018.011.20055) does not allows for saving a PDF as JPG. Am I wrong something?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small script, which converts pgf plots to bitmap pictures. I hope it is also useful for some of you. The script creates a temporary latex file, compiles it to a pdf, and then converts it to a bitmap using the `convert` command.

It can be found here: https://github.com/helgehr/pgf2bitmap

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful!