# TeX figure to .png

Tags: xy-pic, png

Let me begin with a confession: when someone says ``command line'' I nearly pee because I get so scared. I know that means I'm asking my question to the wrong community, and yes, I'm seeing someone about my problems. I don't want to talk about it anymore.

[This thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91472/how-to-save-a-figure-produced-by-tikz-save-export-as-jpg-png-file) asks almost exactly the same question I am interested in. I have two small additions to that post: is it possible to do the exact same thing for a xypic image (I would assume this is the case), and how do I do the part that's all ``code-ish''?

For those who don't want to go read the other thread, here's the simple version: I have three xypic drawings that I want to make .png or .jpg (or whatever) files from. How do I do that?

In case it matters: I use a mac with OSX10.8.4 installed, and when I try really really hard I've managed to find and open a terminal window in the past. I then usually get scared and run away.

Comment: Which IDE are you using ? On [TeXmaker you can right click on the Internal pdf viewer to get file.png](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3396/15717)

Comment: Just learned that a good way for the Mac fearful to get to Terminal is to go to Launchpad and search for the word Terminal. Then look at it for a few minutes and see that it won't bite you, and type "ls" without quotation marks to see a list of all your files!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use the `standalone` documentclass with the `png` option, which will automatically convert the picture into a PNG after the compilation.

Simply compiling the following...

```
\documentclass[png]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
C \ar[r] & D
}
\end{document}
```

... will result in this PNG (in addition to the usual PDF document):

[image]

Comment: png conversion requires: `-shell-escape` or `--enable-write18`(MiKTeX) enabled eg: `pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex`  and [imagemagick installed](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php)

Comment: May be possible Feature request: It would be nice if all `xy-pic` package components could be loaded via standalone Options like TikZ and PSTricks `\documentclass[png,xy-all]{standalone}`

Comment: @texenthusiast: I'm writing in TeXworks (answering your other question) and where/how do I do the ``-shell-escape'' thing to which you refer? This is exactly what is making the compiler sad when I run it.

Comment: I spoke too soon... [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82699/how-to-enable-shell-escape-in-texworks) answers the question I just asked. In combination, the two answers solve the problem I asked about. Woohoo!