# Exporting .png or .jpg files directly from LaTeX code. Possible?

Tags: png

Sometimes it's impossible to upload `.pdf`, `.dvi` and `.ps` files (usually images of diagrams generated with `TiKZ` in my case). There, one wishes to obtain a way to export them directly to a `.png` or some other pic-like file extension. Unfortunately the result I get by taking a snapshot of my `.pdf` is awful.

Which is the better way to get, say, a `.png` out of a LaTeX base code?

Comment: Please search for `\usepackage[convert]{standalone}`. Here are many different posts around. (http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=convert+png and http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=export+png)

Comment: There are a few similar questions, e.g [From inside a LaTeX article, I want to render several parts of the code into a separate png (a "render pass")](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55628)/, [How to save a figure produced by tikz save/export as JPG/PNG file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91472), [TeX figure to .png](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121638), [tikz external use png as default instead of pdf](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74605). Do any of those help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.You can export the latex output to various formats like `.png`, `.svg` , `html` ...etc.

The convert command from the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) suite can convert both DVI and PDF files to PNG.

`convert input.pdf output.png`

**EDIT:** for a good looking png you should provide a higher density than standard like this: 
`convert -density 300 -quality 90 input.pdf output.png`

This [wikipedia page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Export_To_Other_Formats#Multiple_formats) gives you a list of other formats.

Comment: for a good looking png you should provide a higher density than standard like this: `convert -density 300 -quality 90 input.pdf output.png`