# Displaying chemical structure using chemfig in web browser

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I have searched for an answer, but I don't find an answer neither on Google nor here.

Is it possible to use `chemfig` for displaying chemical structure in a website, like it is possible to use the `mhchem` extension with MathJax.

Yes, I know MathJax isn't supporting chemfig, but is there another solution?

Comment: If you have a self-hosted Wordpress website you can use [QuickLaTeX](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/).

Comment: No solution without Wordpress or other CMS?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Assuming you have a local TeX install, you could make PNG files with `chemfig` and the `standalone` document class. Related: [Exporting .png or .jpg files directly from LaTeX code. Possible?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222870/)