# Printing a table as PNG?

Tags: tables, msword, png

I wrote a whole latex file. Due to journal's restrictions, I am forced to submit a word file. Since I have pretty complex tables: I don't want to rebuild in Word and copying tables with snipping tool (Windows) from displayed PDF results in a pretty poor resulution, I wondered whether it is possible to print tables as PNG? Is there a more intelligent way to achieve better results?

Some toy table taken from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables as MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
Team              & P & W & D & L & F  & A & Pts \\
\hline
Manchester United & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 & 5 & 12  \\
Celtic            & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 & 9 &  9  \\
Benfica           & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 & 8 &  7  \\
FC Copenhagen     & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & 8 &  7  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick and dirty: make a screenshot

Comment: Yes, but that's low res.

Comment: Doesn't Word allow you to embed a SVG picture? I know LibreOffice admits it.

Comment: Don't know. How can we get a SVG picture?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to convert a PDF (be it LaTeX generated or not) to SVG. If Word allows you to insert a SVG file, you should consider taking this route. I did it with both LibreOffice Writer and LibreOffice Impress in the past and I was able to even retain the text content as searchable text.

Comment: PS: woah, it seems that you can either use EMF or SVG (the latter only from Word 2016 onwards): https://superuser.com/q/397644/278831 You can then retain all the advantages of vector-quality output!

Comment: You can also open a PDF document directly with Word 2016 onwards. Has saved me hours of work in similar situations.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I'd like to add that the `standalone` class can export the document to PNG format (using ImageMagick's `convert` under the hood), provided that the engine is executed with the `--shell-escape` option:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone} 
\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
Team              & P & W & D & L & F  & A & Pts \\
\hline
Manchester United & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 & 5 & 12  \\
Celtic            & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 & 9 &  9  \\
Benfica           & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 & 8 &  7  \\
FC Copenhagen     & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & 8 &  7  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

When invoked without any options, the used preset will be: PNG format, a density of 300 dpi, no explicit size and the output file name is given
by `\jobname` + `.png` extension. The `standalone` class has other options, so I recommend taking a look at the documentation. `:)`

Comment: This worked quickly and easily for me using OverLeaf!!

Comment: Sorry, but it did not work here... the table is still text (vector)... it is not raster PNG.

Answer (score 12):

Others have provided good answers but I have one that is simpler, at least for me.

1. Compile the Tex file to a PDF
2. Open the PDF with Inkscape (or another vector graphics program like Adobe Illustrator)
3. Size the page to your needs and export a PNG.

Here is my exported PDF at 300 dpi. I like this method because it's easy to re-export your figures as any file format that you need. I think this solution is fairly elegant as it can allow you to save the vectorized graphics if you chose to save it as a PDF file.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to use the `dvipng` program which comes with miktex and texlive.
Assuming your file is called mytable.tex you can use the following:

```
latex mytable.tex
dvipng -D 300 -bg Transparent -T tight -o mytable.tex.png mytable.tex.dvi
```

The first line will generate a .dvi file which is used to generate a .png file with a resolution of 300 dpi in the second line.

You can read more about dvipng here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/dvipng

I prefer to use the standalone document class when creating images with latex, since it crops any white space around the content.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely possible, I found some good reads:

- [Wikibooks on LaTeX/Export To Other Formats](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Export_To_Other_Formats)
- [Existing Answer on here, how to utilize imagemagic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222874/140011)

Your recipe goes like this:

1. [Download image magic](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) - I used the portable version *ImageMagick-7.0.6-3-portable-Q16-x64* for your example. Unpack it.
2. Compile your pdf.
3. Copy your pdf to the image magic folder. Lets call it `tabular.pdf`
4. On Windows: you press `Ctrl+R`and then type `cmd`- this will open a command-line window for for you.
5. Change to the correct directory by typing `cd **"**IMAGMAGICKPATH**"**`. 
   The IMAGMAGICKPATH should be the path were you unpacked your portable IMAGEMAGICK or wherever you installed IMAGEMAGICK. In my case I used `cd "C:\Users\nhck\Downloads\ImageMagick-7.0.6-3-portable-Q16-x64"`.
6. No, to convert, type: `convert -density 300 -quality 100 tabular.pdf tabular.png`

Pay attention about the paths here. In this example I was in the Imagemagick folder and had copied tabular.pdf there as well. The output was saved there as well.

edit: Maybe a comment on convert: You can find the handbook for convert here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php In the example I set the  `density`option to 300 - representing a resolution of 300dpi. This should be sufficient for print. If you plan to resize (enlarge the image) you should go for a higher resolution here. The `quality`option addresses image compression: The lower this value the lower the output file size and the image quality. In your case quality is most important and file size typically doesn't matter, so I set it to 100 - which is the upper limit.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! I downloaded image magic. However, my  slightly stupid question is: where can I allocate command line in this program?

Comment: I've tried to extend the answer for you. Maybe this video also helps:https://youtu.be/MBBWVgE0ewk

Answer (score 3):

Another way to convert to .png format using Texmaker , first compile the LaTeX file using Texmaker, go to view pdf , then write click on that you will have an option to convert to .png format.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a simple way to do this with some online tools (no need for Inkscape or anything of the sort). So for me, the LaTeX PDF I'm working with is 7 pages long. I first downloaded the PDF from Overleaf (the LaTeX editor I'm using) and I go to avepdf.com and upload my whole PDF to the [Extract PDF Pages](https://avepdf.com/extract-pdf-pages) tool. I select page 5, and AvePDF spits back a PDF file containing only one page: namely, the page that contains the table I want.

By the time I have my one-page PDF containing my table, I'm 90% of the way there. You can now use an online tool to directly crop your one-page PDF file to generate a PDF file containing just the table (AvePDF [has a tool](https://avepdf.com/crop-pdf) for this) and then you could use another online tool to convert that cropped PDF to a PNG file (for convenience I again just used the one on the AvePDF website).

Here's the PNG file I ended up with starting from my PDF file containing the table:

[image]

And for your table, I got this:

[image]