# Can somebody give me a simple explanation on how to turn a LaTeX table into a png image?

Tags: tables, texworks, png

Before you say this has been asked before, I did try to look this up and found these thread:

[Printing a table as PNG?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383656/printing-a-table-as-png)

[Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible)

The issue is that I couldn't get the answers to work, probably because I'm not experienced enough. I tried to use the standalone class by writing

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
```

but it gives me an error "Class standalone Warning: Conversion failed! Please ensure that shell escape is enabled (e.g. use '-shell-escape')."

Now, I have no idea how to use this -shell-escape function.

I'm using the software TeXworks and tried implementing the following solution:

[How to enable shell-escape in TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82699/how-to-enable-shell-escape-in-texworks)

But this again just gives me the same error.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

@MadyYuvi:

[image]

Comment: on the commandline use `pdflatex --shell-escape yourfile.tex`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you specify what you mean by commandline?

Comment: @WoeIs Before giving reply, can you confirm what `OS` you are using, i.e., Windows or Mac?

Comment: @MadyYuvi Windows

Comment: @WoeIs Thanks for the confirmation, then you can type the text `cmd`, then the MS-DOS prompt will open by auto, from there, you go to your working path and then try as per DavidCarlisle suggestion...

Comment: @MadyYuvi, can you confirm if my configuration is correct? https://i.imgur.com/ClhaVPI.png

Comment: @WoeIs Sorry, my browser doesn't allow to open the link what you given...

Comment: @MadyYuvi, I've added the image to the main body of this thread.

Comment: @WoeIs Oops, now your question routed to `how to map shortcut to run PDFLaTeX in TeXworks`, I am not an expert in `TeXworks`, I am using `epsilon` as my text editor, some expert in `TeXworks` may reply for this...sorry...

Comment: @MadyYuvi, no worries, so I don't actually need to do any of these things, all I need is to run "pdflatex --shell-escape yourfile.tex" in my commandline? Do you know where the png gets saved to?

Comment: @WoeIs you can keep the `.png` file into the same folder where you keep `TeX` application file or else you can keep the image file into a separate folder, and you can map that particular path by using the tags `\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{./figure/}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi, is there a special way to to make the commandline find the file? It gives me the error "! I can't find file `Testfile.tex'." The file is in a folder called "Test" on my desktop.

Comment: @WoeIs instead of desktop, It is better to keep the folder in a drive, e.g., `D:` or `E:`, etc...

Comment: @MadyYuvi, Unfortunately I only have a C: drive.

Comment: @WoeIs Not an issue, please create a folder `test` in `C:` and place all the files in that folder, then try...

Comment: @MadyYuvi, But my desktop is located in the C: drive, so that shouldn't be an issue right?

Comment: @WoeIs Yes, that's not an issue...

Comment: Did you install ImageMagick ?