# pgfplots - How can I increase TeX's capacity for plotting large datasets? (TeX Live on Windows)

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external

There are several questions and replies on this topic, yet so far I haven't found one which reliably details the steps for **TeX Live and TeXstudio on Windows**. Of course the editor might be an irrelevant part here if this will lead to the permanent solution via the `texmf.cnf` file, but I'd be happy to try the other method as well (i.e. to call pdflatex differently).

The bits I found so far:

- [Increase TeX capacity, as non-root](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27529/increase-tex-capacity-as-non-root) A 3 year old question which lead to the guide in the pgfplots manual (page 458), which is for Ubuntu/Linux.
- [Increasing TeX's main memory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75399/increasing-texs-main-memory) Also about a TeX Live install on a Linux system, it is about 1.5 years old.
- [How to use very large data sets with pgfplots w/o making pdf take a very long time to load?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22020/how-to-use-very-large-data-sets-with-pgfplots-w-o-making-pdf-take-a-very-long-ti) For Ubuntu again, about 3 years old.

I have Windows, Windows 7 to be specific and am using TeX Live (2013) with TexStudio. I am wondering how the steps are for this case? I think this is worth a (new) question since I am arguably not the only one not experienced enough to transfer the steps for Linux to Windows.

Then there are the possibilities named:

- Externalization and
- Bitmap graphics export.

The catch is, the first one is of course very good for any runs of pdflatex except the first one, as I am experiencing this issue when I try to plot the dataset for the first time while using the externalization library. :(

For the second bit, I am a bit foggy on that since I couldn't gather enough facts. [Christian states it might not be that useful for someone with descriptions in it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22020/how-to-use-very-large-data-sets-with-pgfplots-w-o-making-pdf-take-a-very-long-ti#comment47884_22161), yet the same code except for some lines in the end is used (see the TikZ manual on page 689). But that might be an entirely different issue and worth its own question.

Comment: The short answer you can't. LuaTeX helps but if your dataset is beyond some moving threshold you have no other option other than falling back to other external options such as Matplotlib or that software that claims to be the language of scientific computing :) However, a pdf object is hardly ever capable of showing extreme detail. So it is certainly possible that you downsample your data and plot that data set.

Comment: Damnit. I must just above the threshold since I'd like to do groupplots by the size of 3 plots in a column, yet adding the third one fails. :(

Comment: Oh.... there is `each nth point` available for pgfplots! Luckily it works then, by scaling the first one with `=5` and the second one with `=2`. Phew... wow, what a relief.

Comment: @percusse What do you usually do in such a case?

Comment: @henry: Could you please write up your solution as an answer? You can even accept your own answer, and this way your question won't show up on _unanswered_ questions.

Comment: @TomBombadil Imho it's not quite a solution, rather a mitigation of the underlying problem. Actually, it's really not a solution of the problem.