# Is it possible to save each tikzpicture as separate pdf files with given filenames?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, texmaker, standalone

I am using `tikz` to prepare diagrams for a project. Later I have to include these diagrams in the project files, and that's why I want to save each diagram with a given name. Let's say the following is my MWE

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

%==========================
\label{my-first-figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,rounded corners=8pt]
(0,0) -- (0,2) -- (1,3.25) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

%==========================
\label{my-second-figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw [gray] (0,0) circle [radius=2pt]
(1,1) circle [radius=2pt]
(2,1) circle [radius=2pt]
(2,0) circle [radius=2pt];
\draw (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,1) .. (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to save each `tikzpicture`, i.e., each page of the standalone pdf as separate pdf files. For example, after compiling the MWE, I would like to have the first `tikzpicture` as `my-first-figure.pdf` and the second `tikzpicture` as `my-second-figure.pdf`.

I am seeking a solution to reduce inconveniences if, at a later stage, I need to modify a particular diagram. I am not sure if this is possible or not. Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at the externalisation library? It feels like a perfect fit for what you want. It is fully documented in the tikz manual.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423109/export-each-figure-as-a-separate-pdf-file

Answer (score 1):

I found the process description at this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350081).

In the link the author suggests that you can automate the process by modifying the externalization command as in [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22161) or [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40795).

It features a code, which allows you to convert only the figures you want to convert.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]

\tikzset{
png export/.style={
    % First we call ImageMagick; change settings to requirements
    external/system call/.add={}{; convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"},
    % Now we force the PNG figure to be used instead of the PDF
    /pgf/images/external info,
    /pgf/images/include external/.code={
    \includegraphics[width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]{##1.png}
    },
 }
}

\begin{document}

{
% Here we specify the figure will be converted and inserted as PNG
\tikzset{png export}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}

    % This figure will be inserted as PDF
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle (1) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/243501)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos given that the link is to another answer _on this site_ then I think the dangers of link rot are not relevant.

Comment: @AndrewStacey indeed the link will be ok but it seems that the question to which the current answer is posted is a duplicate of the linked question (or at least a very near duplicate) and should be closed as such, or maybe as a duplicate of a different externalization question that is a bit more tailored towards pdf output.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I've edited the answer and hope to collaborate in a better way.